# What openings should be played in a simul?

Tags: opening, simultaneous

What openings are usually good for a simul?  I'm assuming that it's an all-comers simul, so there could be strong players mixed in.  Does the answer change if the strength of the opponents is known ahead of time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've always heard that person giving a simul should strive for quiet positions, where they can use their superior understanding and not have to calculate much, and his opponents should strive for the opposite: complex, tactical positions. Even GMs can miscalculate while giving a simul, since they have so little time per move, and so many boards to worry about. This makes sense to me, and I think this holds regardless whether strength of participants is known in advance.

Having said that, there are some crazy Morphy and Alekhine tactical wins in simuls, even blindfold simuls.